# How can I tell when [OpenFeint initialize....] is complete?

Tags: ios, openfeint

If the user accepts OpenFeint, it is easy because either the `offlineUserLoggedIn` or `userLoggedIn` delegate methods will be invoked.  If the user rejects OpenFeint, there doesn't seem to be any indication.  There's `[OpenFeint hasUserApprovedFeint]`, but that returns `NO` if the user has rejected OpenFeint or if they are staring at the approval screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across the same problem.  My proposed solution:

Create a Class that implements the `OpenFeintAddOn` protocol.  `initializeAddOn` will be called once OF is initialized.

HOWEVER the user will not be finished logging in when this is called.  If you are just wanting to make sure OF is initialized, then this should work.  If you need to know if the user is logged in or not, I would suggest adding listeners to `offlineUserLoggedIn` and `userLoggedIn` that would refresh your settings once they are called.  You will probably need these functions anyway in case the user logs in later during your game after the initialize.